# Action<T> delegate in function signature parameter - unclear about type

Tags: c#, function, lambda, functional-programming

I have a working piece of C# code that uses the Renci.SshNet package. I'm uploading a file, and the relevant function has the following signature:

```
public void UploadFile(Stream input, string path, Action<ulong> uploadCallback = null);
```

I'm calling it like this (which is all fine):

```
Client.UploadFile(UploadStream, RemoteFile,
    uploadcallback =>
    {
        Logger.Info("Uploaded {0}", CurrentFile);
        ArchiveList.Add(CurrentFile);
    });
```

What I'm not clear about is why the uploadCallback parameter is `Action<ulong>`. Is that just what you need if you're putting a lambda expression in when calling it?

Comment: You're not calling the overload that you have shown here.

Comment: in your case Client.UploadFile is a static method and bool canOverride field seems to be out of the picture, unless the signature has a default value

Comment: `uploadcallback` is the parameter of the `Action<ulong>` you're passing to `UploadFile` so has type `ulong`, not `Action<ulong>`. You also aren't passing the `canOverride` argument in your example.

Comment: @Zinov it's an instance of Renci.SshNet.SftpClient.

Comment: Sorry, I had the wrong method signature there, fixed.

Comment: @Lee - right, but why ulong?

Comment: Action<ulong> is the delegate that seems the be called after the upload file is complete. The ulong on this case is not clear to me, why it needs a ulong parameter

Comment: @AlanB Look in the documentation to see what the parameter provided logically represents.  That's exactly what it's there for.

Comment: Because that's the parameter type of an `Action<ulong>` which is what `uploadCallback` is declared as. Are you asking what the corresponding value represents?

Comment: The `Action` you provide will be called from `UploadFile`. That method does something and then executed that delegate. Furthermore it gives you some information provided as the delegates parameter, which in this special case is of type `ulong`.

Comment: I mocked up an example with the same sort of function and I get it now. @HimFromBeere if you want to make that comment the answer I'll accept it as it's the clearest.#

Comment: It's the byte size of the uploaded file, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

I had copied the anonymous function from an example, however calling it correctly makes it obvious what's going on.

Not:

```
Client.UploadFile(UploadStream, RemoteFile,
    uploadcallback =>
    {
        Logger.Info("Uploaded {0}", CurrentFile);
        ArchiveList.Add(CurrentFile);
    });
```

But:

```
 Client.UploadFile(UploadStream, RemoteFile,
    (ulong u) => 
    {
        Logger.Info("Uploaded {0}, {1} bytes.", CurrentFile, u.ToString());
            ArchiveList.Add(CurrentFile);
    });
```